# Selecting xml_nodes for patent data using library(rvest) and library(xml) in R

Tags: xml, r, rvest, magrittr

Given the following (quasi)xml-structure of EPO's patent Server REPO:

```
<ep-patent-document id="EP79301547B1" file="EP79301547NWB1.xml" lang="en" country="EP" doc-number="0007815" kind="B1" date-publ="19871021" status="n" dtd-version="ep-patent-document-v1-1">
<SDOBI lang="en">
<B000>...</B000>
<B100>...</B100>
<B200>
<B210>79301547.0</B210>
<B220>
<date>19790801</date>
</B220>
<B240/>
<B250>en</B250>
<B251EP>en</B251EP>
<B260>en</B260>
</B200>
<B300>...</B300>
<B400>...</B400>
<B500>...</B500>
<B700>...</B700>
<B800>...</B800>
</SDOBI>
<!--  EPO <DP n="1">  -->
<!--  EPO <DP n="2">  -->
<description id="desc" lang="en">...</description>
<claims id="claims01" lang="en">...</claims>
<claims id="claims02" lang="de">...</claims>
<claims id="claims03" lang="fr">...</claims>
</ep-patent-document>
```

I would like to select the number in node "B210" and the text in "description".

Using

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(XML)
library(magrittr)

files1993 <- list.files("~/Downloads", full.names=TRUE, recursive=TRUE)
y <- files1993[1]
parse1993 <- htmlParse(y) 

parse1993 %>% xml_nodes("description")
parse1993 %>% xml_nodes("SDOBI") %>% xml_nodes("B210")
```

I do get the description text but nothing for B210. In fact, the command won't work for any information given in . Do I have to convert the information given in SDOBI into text? I am a little lost here. Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: why not use `xmlParse`?  `parse1993 %>% xml_nodes("SDOBI") %>% xml_nodes("B210")` works fine then

Comment: Try `xml2` from Hadley: `library(xml2);xml <- xml('...your.example...');xml_text(xml_find(xml, "//B210 | //description"));# [1] "79301547.0" "..."  `.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry that this response is a bit late but wanted to respond anyway in case someone else needs help on this same topic.

First of all, working with the EPO api is a huge pain in the butt.  There xml is a bear and the data can be quite dirty and inconsistent.

[PatentData.io](http://patentdata.io/) seems to be a better option.  They have the EPO data sets, cleaned, and piped out through a modern RESTful JSON api.  [rjson](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjson/index.html) is much easier to work with.  They also provide some cool advanced searching and analytics functions if you are looking to get fancy.

They are still in beta now but I think they are actively taking new beta users.  Check it out.